# c++ derived class ,inheritance and objects poly

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, virtual, shapes

i have created a project that uses poly and inheritance. 
the base class is "Shape" and the derived are "Circle" and "Polygon" which "Triangle" and "Rectangle" are derived by "Polygon " 
in addition i need to create a class Point that will initialize the each shape constructor using Point object .

Two points were created - Point o(0,0),Point a(0,1)
and a new circle 'shape' was created  -new Circle   (o,a)
im trying to calculate the area this way : 
a.getX() - a.getY() [this is the radius] * 3.14

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Point.h"
#include "Shape.h"
#include "Circle.h"
using namespace std;


void main ()
{
    Point o(0,0);
    Point a(0,1);
    Point b(1,0);

    Shape *shapes[]=    
    {       
        new Circle   (o,a)
        new Rectangle(a,b);
        new Triangle (o,a,b);

    };

        cout<<" area= "<<shapes[0]->area(); 
//should print pt1.getY()-pt0.getY() * 3.14
}
```

shape.h

```
#ifndef SHAPE_H
#define SHAPE_H

class Shape
{
public:
    virtual double area() const= 0;

};
#endif
```

circle.h

```
#ifndef CIRCLE_H
#define CIRCLE_H
#include "Shape.h"
#include "Point.h"
class Circle:public Shape
{
public :
     Circle(Point pt0,Point pt1);
     double area();
private :
    Point pt0, pt1;
};
#endif
```

circle.cpp

```
#include "Circle.h"
#include "Point.h"

Circle::Circle(Point pt0,Point pt1)//(o,a) from the main
{
    this->pt0=pt0;
    this->pt1=pt1;
}

double Circle:: area()
{

    return pt1.getY()-pt0.getY() * 3.14;
}
```

Comment: That's a lot of code and no question.

Comment: Shouldn't circle class contain only one point of center and radius?

Comment: @Valentin - this is the given main.cpp, i need to use it as is.
the

Comment: @JohnZwinck - ok let me edit the post to be more clear.

Comment: @EliasE you can't specify a circle by two points, only if they lay on diameter

Comment: @Valentin - thanks for the quick reply
 i have two point - one is the center(0,0) the other defines diameter point(0,1)- using both of them i can calculate the radius and so the area

Comment: @EliasE so the problem is to calculate the radius?

Comment: the problem is here, 
double Circle:: area()
{

    return pt1.getY()-pt0.getY() * 3.14;
}

Comment: @EliasE And, the problem is..? Note: you do know, that following the rules of math, multiplication is done before subtraction? It's the same behavior in C++, as well. Have a look at [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence).

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius , i know rule maths, its isnt my issue now ,

Answer (score 0):

This formula is wrong:

```
pt1.getY()-pt0.getY() * 3.14;
```

First there is the missing `()` or else you are multiplying PI by the `pt0` only.

Second, a circle cannot be defined by two points in the line: you need three, and the computation is not so easy. I think that you want the first point to be the center, and the second one to lie in the line. Then the radius is easy:

```
double dx = pt1.getX() - pt0.getX();
double dy = pt1.getY() - pt0.getY();
double radius = sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);
double area = 2 * radius * PI;
```